# delay in email delivery send using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, email, smtp

I'm using codeigniter 3.x. problem is i can send email using codeigniter email library and smtp, but email only delivered after 4-10mins. how can I reduce the time gap. please give me some advice.

```
        $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
        $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
        $config['smtp_user'] = 'myemail';/*email goes here*/
        $config['smtp_pass'] = 'mypass'; /*email pwd goes here*/
        $config['smtp_port'] = 465; 
        $config['smtp_timeout'] = 5;
        $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
        $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
        $config['priority'] = 1;
        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
        $this->load->library('parser');


        $this->email->from('my mail');
        $this->email->to('tomail');

        $this->email->subject('subject');
        $this->email->message('message');
```

Comment: wt is your code should show me?

Comment: did you added       $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");    try and let us know

Comment: @GoldunoSupport that makes no sense at all, and I don't think this is a codeigniter related issue. Since codeigniter doesn't use any queeing or anything like that.

Comment: @Jordy, yhea sometimes a silly thing makes disaster, please let him try meanwhile he is sharing the code.

Comment: @Golduno Support   " $this->email->set_newline("\r\n"); " this is for Newline character. and wont affect the speed of delivery.

Comment: Have you tried it? and please share the code with masking ur credentials i.e. username and password

Answer (score 0):

First check error log and mail service is working or not.

then you this code:

```
$ci = get_instance();
$ci->load->library('email');
$config['protocol'] = "smtp";
$config['smtp_host'] = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$config['smtp_port'] = "465";
$config['smtp_user'] = "abc@gmail.com"; 
$config['smtp_pass'] = "yourpassword";
$config['charset'] = "utf-8";
$config['mailtype'] = "html";
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";

$ci->email->initialize($config);

$ci->email->from('abc@gmail.com', 'abc');
$list = array('xxx@gmail.com');
$ci->email->to($list);
$this->email->reply_to('my-email@gmail.com', 'Explendid Videos');
$ci->email->subject('This is an email test');
$ci->email->message('It is working. Great!');
$ci->email->send();
```

I hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Its not code igniter library problem may be your server smtp connection is working slow. to confirm if you using linux then try

$ sudo apt-get install heirloom-mailx

echo "This is the message body and contains the message" | mailx -v -r    "someone@example.com" -s "This is the subject" -S smtp="mail.example.com:587" -S smtp-use-starttls -S smtp-auth=login -S smtp-auth-user="someone@example.com" -S smtp-auth-password="abc123" -S ssl-verify=ignore yourfriend@gmail.com

for more check 
http://www.binarytides.com/linux-mail-with-smtp/

and check is it delivered fast or slow?